# Adding Data from database to custom jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to add the databases to specific column,row the column always is the same but the row change. So I enter the variable and trying to add one to the number but not luck all is printing are 0 so is not adding any number to the variable for that reason my table stay in the same row and never change. I try i++; i=i+1; all I have is 0 on the println(). Im using Netbeans.

```
     Statement stmt = null;
      String sql="select * from gateway where date= "+id;
      try{
      Connect conn=new Connect();
      stmt = conn.makeStatement();        
       rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);            
        while(rs.next()) {
            int i=0;
            Object ids = rs.getString("Business");
            Object items = rs.getString("GatewayJob");
            Object descriptions = rs.getString("Status");
            Object quantitys = rs.getString("Timework");
            Object price = rs.getString("Notes");      

            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(ids,i, 0 );
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(items, i, 1);
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(descriptions, i, 2);
           jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(quantitys, i, 3);
          jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(price, i, 4);              
          System.out.println(i);
        i++;
        }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because *i* is reset to 0 every while loop.
So you should put int i=0; before while().

```
int i=0;
while(rs.next()){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In you code

```
while(rs.next()) {
            int i=0;
```

move the `int i = 0;` to before your `while loop`

this statement will reset `i` back to 0 everytime

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the setValueAt() method. This implies you have loaded the TableModel with a bunch of rows containing null values which is a bad design as you don't know how many rows the query will return.

Instead, you should be dynamically building the TableModel by adding a new row to the model in your loop.

See [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/), especially the `Table From Database Example` code for a simple solution that uses the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: This will pull the entire database column (no need it).

Comment: @gyuhh, Then don't use "select *", or only get the data from the columns that you need using the basic code your provided above. The point is to build the Vector and add the row to the model. `Using setValueAt(...) is simply a terrible coding practice`.

Answer (score 1):

try this code. im using String connection. this codes is running.

```
String sql = "select * from tblstudent";

try{

database.Query(sql);

int inc=0;

while(database.dataTable.next()){

         Object a = database.dataTable.getInt("StudentID");
         Object b = database.dataTable.getString("Firstname");
         Object c = database.dataTable.getString("Lastname");
         Object d = database.dataTable.getString("Gender");
         Object e = database.dataTable.getInt("CourseID");

         tblStudent.getModel().setValueAt(a, inc, 0 );
         tblStudent.getModel().setValueAt(b, inc, 1);
         tblStudent.getModel().setValueAt(c, inc, 2);
         tblStudent.getModel().setValueAt(d, inc, 3);
         tblStudent.getModel().setValueAt(e, inc, 4);              

         inc++;
     }
 }
catch(SQLException ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
 }

}
```